# Powerpoint Chart: Query on xlValue and xlCategory of Axis class

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

In PPT charts, under the **xlAxisType** class there are three members. ***xlCategory*** is one such member and **xlValue** is another member. There is a collection named ***CategoryNames*** of the Axes class which I can make use for the type **xlCategory** but not for **xlValues**.

I would like to know which members of axis class can i make use of for the type ***xlValue*** . Intellisense is also not working for my case. [Please see pic for clarity & code below].

*Note: I have switched on the Show Hidden Member in the Object Browser*

```
   'Code snippet
   If ThisShape.HasChart = True Then
        
        Dim ThisChart As Chart
        Set ThisChart = ThisShape.Chart

        arr = ThisChart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames
        MsgBox UBound(arr)
  
        Dim CategoryList As Variant
        CategoryList = ThisChart.Axes(xlValue).CategoryNames
        MsgBox UBound(CategoryList)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: .CategoryNames applies only to the Categories axis. Here is Microsoft's page with Axis Methods and Properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.axis

Comment: Thanks John. But that doesn't say anything about which methods and properties applies only for xlCategory or xlValue or both. Is this something that can be figured out only by trials ?

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft's documentation is not that fine-grained. Most Axis properties will work for both, you were lucky enough to pick one that doesn't!